# hide nodes in a 3D model - forgeviewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I want to hide specific set (an array of dbIds) of nodes in the model.

I tried using [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hidding-completely-viewer-nodes-no-ghosting) example but it hides all the nodes.

What would be the best way to get this done.

viewer version - 6.*

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach explained in the linked article uses an internal implementation (`viewer.impl`) so we cannot guarantee it will be available in newer versions of the viewer. A cleaner approach would be to simply hide the elements using the official [hide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#hide-node-model) method, and then disabling the "Ghost hidden objects" viewer option:
[image]

If you still need to completely disable an element in the scene, try the following approach:

```js
function disableElement(viewer, model, dbid) {
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragid) {
        frags.setFragOff(fragid, true);
    });
    viewer.invalidate(true, true, true);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Petr 

is it possible to set that setting from the code level ???

Comment: Yes, you can use the [setGhosting](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setghosting-value) method.